# Separating a sentence into words using regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm trying to do the above. For example:

```
"This is a sentence I'm currently writing, potentially with punctuation dotted in: item1, item2, item3. That is all."
```

should split into individual words:

```
This
is 
a
sentence
I'm
```

and so on.

I'm just struggling to write the regexp. I know this would be pretty easy using a delimiter or two, but trying to learn more about regexp.

Comment: just split according to this `\s+` regex. or use `string.split()`

Comment: Write the "so on" part. Your question is ambiguous. We cannot tell what you want after that. And, what is your question?

Comment: Do you want `writing,` or `writing`, `in:` or `in` ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split your input according to one or more space characters.

```
> "This is a sentence I'm currently writing, potentially with punctuation dotted in: item1, item2, item3. That is all.".split(/\s+/)
=> ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "I'm", "currently", "writing,", "potentially", "with", "punctuation", "dotted", "in:", "item1,", "item2,", "item3.", "That", "is", "all."]

> "This is a sentence I'm currently writing, potentially with punctuation dotted in: item1, item2, item3. That is all.".split()
=> ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "I'm", "currently", "writing,", "potentially", "with", "punctuation", "dotted", "in:", "item1,", "item2,", "item3.", "That", "is", "all."]
```

**OR**

Match one or more non-space characters.

```
> "This is a sentence I'm currently writing, potentially with punctuation dotted in: item1, item2, item3. That is all.".scan(/\S+/)
=> ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "I'm", "currently", "writing,", "potentially", "with", "punctuation", "dotted", "in:", "item1,", "item2,", "item3.", "That", "is", "all."]
```

Answer (score 0):

use [split](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/split)

```
2.0.0-p481 :001 > a="This is a sentence I'm currently writing, potentially with punctuation dotted in: item1, item2, item3. That is all."
 => "This is a sentence I'm currently writing, potentially with punctuation dotted in: item1, item2, item3. That is all." 
2.0.0-p481 :002 > a.split
 => ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "I'm", "currently", "writing,", "potentially", "with", "punctuation", "dotted", "in:", "item1,", "item2,", "item3.", "That", "is", "all."] 
2.0.0-p481 :003 >
```

**OR** USE LOOP TO FRAME A WORD ON EACH LINE

```
2.0.0-p481 :036 > a="This is a sentence I'm currently writing, potentially with punctuation dotted in: item1, item2, item3. That is all."
 => "This is a sentence I'm currently writing, potentially with punctuation dotted in: item1, item2, item3. That is all." 
2.0.0-p481 :037 > a.split.each{ |i|  puts "#{i}"}
This
is
a
sentence
I'm
currently
writing,
potentially
with
punctuation
dotted
in:
item1,
item2,
item3.
That
is
all.
 => ["This", "is", "a", "sentence", "I'm", "currently", "writing,", "potentially", "with", "punctuation", "dotted", "in:", "item1,", "item2,", "item3.", "That", "is", "all."] 
2.0.0-p481 :038 >
```